Matmul-free LLM ternary weights?
I've been reading "Scalable MatMul-free Language Modeling"  that uses ternary weights.
I wanted to inspect the weights, so I did the following:
from safetensors import safe_open
from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download

# Change here to your model name
name = 'ridger/MMfreeLM-370M'  # replace with your model name

# Download the safetensors file
file_path = hf_hub_download(repo_id=name, filename="model.safetensors")

# Open the safetensors file and inspect its contents
with safe_open(file_path, framework="pt") as f:
    for key in f.keys():
        tensor = f.get_tensor(key)
        print(f"Key: {key}, Shape: {tensor.shape}, Dtype: {tensor.dtype}")

The first few lines are :
Key: lm_head.norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: lm_head.weight, Shape: torch.Size([32000, 1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.embeddings.weight, Shape: torch.Size([32000, 1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn.f_proj.norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn.f_proj.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024, 1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn.g_norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn.g_proj.norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn.g_proj.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024, 1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn.i_proj.norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn.i_proj.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024, 1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn.o_proj.norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn.o_proj.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024, 1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.attn_norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.mlp.down_proj.norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([2816]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.mlp.down_proj.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024, 2816]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.mlp.gate_proj.norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.mlp.gate_proj.weight, Shape: torch.Size([5632, 1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16
Key: model.layers.0.mlp_norm.weight, Shape: torch.Size([1024]), Dtype: torch.bfloat16

Next I did :
from safetensors import safe_open
from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download
import torch

# Change here to your model name
name = 'ridger/MMfreeLM-370M'  # replace with your model name

# Download the safetensors file
file_path = hf_hub_download(repo_id=name, filename="model.safetensors")

# Open the safetensors file and extract the specific weights
key_to_extract = "model.layers.0.attn.f_proj.weight"
with safe_open(file_path, framework="pt") as f:
    tensor = f.get_tensor(key_to_extract)

print(tensor.shape)
print(tensor.flatten()[:20])

The output was :
torch.Size([1024, 1024])
tensor([ 0.5742,  0.2363, -0.0845, -1.3906,  0.4824,  0.1738, -0.8945,  0.1221,
        -0.1543, -0.0276, -0.2100,  0.0942, -0.4648, -0.0796, -1.0938, -0.2100,
         0.2471, -0.5703,  0.0713, -0.1641], dtype=torch.bfloat16)

I thought that the weights were supposed to be ternary.
Completely confused.

The safest guess I have is either that the weights are stored as seen, however they get quantized to ternary values during inference (or training), meaning that for the sake of the forward pass the weights are indeed used as ternary values, even if for the sake of storing them they arent.
In fact, briefly skimming the paper, on page 2, this exact approach gets mentioned. (around where reference [7] gets cited)
